# How to fix the 'The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata' error?

Tags: pivot-table, dask

I have a table of price updates in the format (timestamp, price, amount).
The timestamp is a datetime, price categorical and amount float64. The timestamp column is set as an index.
My goal is to get the amount available at each price level at each point in time.
First, I use the pivot to spread the prices into columns, and then forward fill.

```
pivot = price_table.pivot_table(index = 'timestamp', 
columns = 'price', values = 'amount')
pivot_ffill = pivot.fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

I can `compute` or apply `head` to `pivot_ffill` and it works fine.
Clearly, there are still NAs at the beginning of the table where there have been no updates yet.
When I apply

```
pivot_nullfill = pivot_ffill.fillna(0)
pivot_nullfill.head()
```

I do get an error
`The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata`. I tried replacing the zero with `0.0` or `float(0)`, but to no avail. As the previous steps work, I strongly suspect it has something to do with the `fillna`, but due to the delayed calculations that does not have to be true.

Does someone know what causes this? Thank you!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-f8ab344c7939> in <module>
----> 1 pivot_ffill.fillna(0).head()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in head(self, n, npartitions, compute)
    896 
    897         if compute:
--> 898             result = result.compute()
    899         return result
    900 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    154         dask.base.compute
    155         """
--> 156         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    157         return result
    158 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    396     keys = [x.__dask_keys__() for x in collections]
    397     postcomputes = [x.__dask_postcompute__() for x in collections]
--> 398     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    399     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    400 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py in get(dsk, result, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
     74     results = get_async(pool.apply_async, len(pool._pool), dsk, result,
     75                         cache=cache, get_id=_thread_get_id,
---> 76                         pack_exception=pack_exception, **kwargs)
     77 
     78     # Cleanup pools associated to dead threads

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    460                         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    461                     else:
--> 462                         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    463                 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    464                 state['cache'][key] = res

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\compatibility.py in reraise(exc, tb)
    110         if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
    111             raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
--> 112         raise exc
    113 
    114     import pickle as cPickle

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    228     try:
    229         task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 230         result = _execute_task(task, data)
    231         id = get_id()
    232         result = dumps((result, id))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    116     elif istask(arg):
    117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
--> 118         args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
    119         return func(*args2)
    120     elif not ishashable(arg):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    116     elif istask(arg):
    117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
--> 118         args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
    119         return func(*args2)
    120     elif not ishashable(arg):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    118         args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
--> 119         return func(*args2)
    120     elif not ishashable(arg):
    121         return arg

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\optimization.py in __call__(self, *args)
    940                              % (len(self.inkeys), len(args)))
    941         return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey,
--> 942                         dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
    943 
    944     def __reduce__(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in get(dsk, out, cache)
    147     for key in toposort(dsk):
    148         task = dsk[key]
--> 149         result = _execute_task(task, cache)
    150         cache[key] = result
    151     result = _execute_task(out, cache)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    118         args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
--> 119         return func(*args2)
    120     elif not ishashable(arg):
    121         return arg

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\compatibility.py in apply(func, args, kwargs)
     91     def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
     92         if kwargs:
---> 93             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     94         else:
     95             return func(*args)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in apply_and_enforce(*args, **kwargs)
   3800             if not np.array_equal(np.nan_to_num(meta.columns),
   3801                                   np.nan_to_num(df.columns)):
-> 3802                 raise ValueError("The columns in the computed data do not match"
   3803                                  " the columns in the provided metadata")
   3804             else:

ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message should have give you a suggestion of how to fix the situation. We assume you are loading from CSV (the question doesn't say), so you would probably end up with a line like

```
df = dd.read_csv(..., dtype={...})
```

which instructs the pandas reader on the dtypes you want to enforce, since you know more information than pandas does. That ensures that all partitions have the same types for all columns - see the **notes** part of the [docs](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv).

Comment: I was actually loading a pandas data frame to dask using `from_pandas`. This method does not have a `dtype` argument. Is there a way around saving to csv and reloading?

Comment: Writing and loading to CSV seems to work now. Thanks again!